# Manage dependency of django model relations for migrating database

Tags: django, postgresql, oracle

I'm working on a Django project using Oracle database. I'm going to migrate all of data from Oracle database to Postgres database. My database has many tables with too many ForeignKeys, ManyToMany and OneToOne relations together.
I can migrate drips and drapes in the first solution, which requires too much resources. I'm going to migrate these by only one command.

I need a sorted list of all tables managed by django which are sorted by their dependencies. In other words a table which is referred by other tables through ForeignKeys should be sorted first. What shall I do to handle this?